# $OABC$ is a parallelogram with $O$ at the origin and $a,b,c$ are the position vectors of the points $A,B, and$ $C$.

Tags: vectors

$OABC$ is a parallelogram with $O$ at the origin and $a,b,c$  are the position vectors of the points $A,B, and$ $C$. $P$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $Q$ is the point on $OB$ such that $OQ:QB$ is 2:1.
Prove $APQ$ is a straight line

I keep seeming to come round in circles in trying to prove this and it is just seeming unnecessarily messy.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? You define a bunch of points, but don't say what it is you need to prove about them.

Comment: added it in. sorry i missed a bit off

Comment: $b=a+c$, $p=\frac12(b+c)$ and $q=\frac13b$. You need to show that $p-a$ is a scalar multiple of $q-a$.

Comment: But if I do that there isn't a common scalar for both c and b terms

Answer (score 0):

If you mark midpoint of $AC$ with $R$ you see that $R$ is also a midpoint for $OB$ since $OABC$ is a paralellogram.

So $Q$ is a gravity center for $ABC$ since $BQ:QR=2:1$, so $Q$ is also on $AP$.